# How to set the JVM Memory for Solr running on an Azure App Service

Tags: solr, content-search, performance

If you are following one of these blog posts on setting up Solr in an Azure App Service (instead of an VM) such as: https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/installing-solr-app-service-in-sitecore-azure-paas, https://www.iamashishsharma.com/2020/11/install-solr-as-azure-app-service.html or https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/10/08/setting-up-solr-in-cloud-as-an-app-service/

All of them use the default setting for JVM memory (memory for the Java Virtual Machine) - which is 512MB. Generally this isn't enough for Solr in Production and needs increasing to a few GB. It will depend on how much you use search.

On our previous on-prem 16GB VM we had the JVM memory set to 11GB (around 70% of the RAM). I wasn't sure how to do this when running Solr in an Azure App Service though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this I found I needed to pass an command argument `-m` in the web.config where the start command is issued like so:

```
 <httpPlatform processPath="%HOME%\site\wwwroot\bin\solr.cmd"
   arguments="start -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -m 11g"
   startupTimeLimit="20"
   startupRetryCount="10"
   stdoutLogEnabled="true">
```

This can be passed in megabytes instead if you prefer, e.g: `-m 1024m` = 1GB.

**Note:** I did try to see If I could change settings in: *solr.cmd, solr.in.cmd* and *solr.in.sh* to do this instead but couldn't get any of the changes to work so If you know a better way of doing this please comment or add another answer.